# how to remove ' from string

Tags: sql

Im trying to use the TRIM command in SQL to Remove special characters from a string. thing is i cant seem to figure out how to remove the ' character like how when people use it in their surname.

e.g O'Reilly

in order to remove a character i have to quote it, but how can put in quotes or identify the character ' when it is used for quoting.

Comment: trim remove spaces not special characters. Use replace to remove them

Comment: Why you want remove the ' ?  Why dont save it with the name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `replace()` and not `trim()`.  Then, the escaping of single quotes requires doubling it, plus the outer single quotes.  So:

```
replace(name, '''', '')
---------------^^  escaped single quote
--------------^--^ string delimiter for the single quote character
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Replace function to replace that character (').

```
replace(name,"'","");
```

[Link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql)

[Link 2](https://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-replace.html)